# How projectile motion should be simulated?

Tags: java, libgdx

I am making a simulator using libgdx about projectile motion, something like [this](http://www.design-simulation.com/IP/simulationlibrary/flashsimulations/AirProjectile.swf). Based on my understanding velocity x and velocity y are seperate and don't affect each other, so the object being trown an an angle will fall due to gravity. So this means if the object initial speed is 40 m/s then it means it only refers horizontally? or x = 40m/s, So what are the formulas to follow when computing for the velocity of x and y with initial speed and angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alnitak has the initial velocity part nailed on - you need to know the initial speed, and the initial angle (measured up from the horizontal), then you can use his formulae to work out the initial x and y components of the velocity (call them `x0` and `y0` - these are fixed numbers, or constants).

All that answer was missing is how to calculate how those x and y components of velocity change over time.

Assuming no air resistance (probably fair for a typical game) there is no horizontal acceleration, meaning the x component stays fixed at `x0` for all time.

Vertically you have acceleration due to gravity, `g`, which is typically approximated by `9.8ms-2` but you can tweak it to be whatever feels right.

To get the vertical velocity, `y`, after time `t` seconds, given that it started with initial vertical velocity `y0` (which you already calculated), you can do:

`y = y0 - 9.8*t`

(subtracting since gravity goes down)

So at time `t` your velocity is `(x0, y0 - 9.8*t)`.

Google 'kinematics equations' for any more info

Comment: Thanks, since I can set the angle of the projectile, so what should be the origin of my object? And how to calculate the distance that the projectile reached?

Comment: The origin depends on your implementation, but (0,0) works well. To get the position there are equations for that too, but you'll probably need to use a deltatime. Check out http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Answer (score 1):

"Speed" is the scalar version of "velocity", so if you imagine the `x` and `y` components of velocity as forming a right-angled triangle the speed is therefore `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` per Pythagoras.

It follows from that that the initial `x` velocity is actually `speed * cos(angle)` and `y` is `speed * sin(angle)` where `angle` is measured in radians from the horizon.

Comment: so if I follow these formulas, I should be able to make an accurate simulator? like it follows real world proven theories?

Comment: Well no, that's not entirely sufficient - an "accurate" simulator would also take air friction (drag) into account.

Comment: ... and "spin" of the projectile. The trajectory of a tumbling bullet will be significantly different from a non-spinning ball , e.g.

Comment: @Fildor ok, scratch "not entirely sufficient" - more like "not even remotely close to 'accurate' " :)

Comment: but accurate for projectile motion only?

Comment: as we used to say in math class - "assuming a dimensionless mass moving in a vacuum" ...

Comment: If I understand correctly this is what should I do: float speed += 40 * deltaTime(assuming that the initial speed is 40m/s) then to make my object move in a projectile motion: sprite.x = speed * cos(angle) and sprite.y = speed * sin(angle). So sprite.x is velocity x and sprite.y is velocity y?

Comment: @StormAsdg if you don't understand high-school physics then I'm afraid this is probably beyond you.  Think in terms of "force" and "acceleration".  At each delta in time determine the forces acting on your projectile.  Then use `F = ma` in each dimension to calculate the _acceleration_.  Use that acceleration to modify the _velocity_ vector, and then use that vector to modify the _position_ vector.

Comment: and in a drag-less scenario the only "force" acting on your projectile is gravity, in the `-y` direction

Comment: I did my computations and I realized that I do not need to add to the float speed a value of 40 every second, because velocity x is constant and once y has been calculated all I need to do is decrease it by 9.8 every second: y = speed * sin(angle) then on my render method: sprite.y += y * deltaTime; y -= 9.8 * deltaTime; is it correct?

Comment: Like I said, you've no horizontal force (in the absence of drag...)

Comment: Also, I suggest using variables named e.g. `vx` for "velocity in the x direction".  `x` itself should be reserved for the _position_

Comment: @Alnitak one last question, so my object position is at 0,0 coordinate and the origin is at the bottom left of my object, or should I set the origin at the center of the object?

Answer (score 1):

First off,

> So this means if the object initial speed is 40 m/s then it means it only refers horizontally
>   Nop 40m/s(Lets say this as **v**) means that the initial launch velocity and it can be 'factorized' into 2 parts which are perpendicular to each other, **x=vCos(angle)** and **y=vSin(angle)**

So if you somehow manage to draw points on screen according to these formulas then you can plot the path.(The exact formula for x/y at any moment on flight is Y=yt−0.5gt**2 and X=xt ).. remember these formulas only work when there is no air,

once there is air resistance things do bit weird and calculus takes over the whole thing.. i believe that's explains the situation you are in..